# How to make TableViewCell Dynamic?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uitableview

[image]

How to click cell index 0 show more like image 2.
After click collap cell index 0 and show detail

Comment: You don't need to add additional information as an answer, just edit your question. Also there are many tutorials about it: [collapsible tableview](https://www.google.com/search?q=swift+collapsible+table+view&oq=swift+collapsible+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l7.7617j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). You can ask here with your code samples after you've tried something.

Answer (score 0):

1.add a bool property to your model, noCollap = false

2.change the value when cell clicked, noCollap = true

3.reload tableView, in heightForRowAtIndexPath, change a cell's height depend on yourDataArray[indexPath.row].noCollap